# Need help configuring server for accessing it with PuTTY

Tags: server, putty

I'm new to Linux and I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS(32 bit) on a VM (VirtualBox). I followed every step as described on this site and other forums so I managed to install it.

Now I need help to configure ip address and `ssh` so that I can access it with PuTTY on Windows to Linux (on VM).

I need a step by step guide regarding this. I tried some methods but didn't have luck so I need someone who's already experienced and has done this to show me because its very important for me to set this up.

If someone can help me I'll give my TeamViewer id so that I can follow instructions and see how it is done. It would really mean to me and I would be very grateful.

---

OK...thanks for answers ....but i already done this
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
After that i did
sudo service ssh restart
I also did
sudo apt-get update

I now configured static ip and also port 22 is listened,but in putty i have problem which is "Connection refused".It can't connect...i just tried this earlier and this happens over and over again.I tried to find answers how to solve that issue but didnt have luck,so thats why i'm asking someone to show me that directly on my local machine.
I get errors like Connection refused or Connection timed out.
Dont know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.
Dusan.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring IP address depends on the type of network access you have. Lookup 'man ifconfig'; network type usually should be eth0 (wired ethernet) or wlan0 (wireless); since this is a server we are talking about, eth0 is the safer bet.

For ssh access to the server it needs to be running an ssh daemon. On Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS, this is available using

> > > sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Answer (score 0):

your computer OS is window and then you install ubuntu on virtualbox ? am i correct?

first, you must install the `ssh-server` on your ubuntu desktop, open your terinal and type this :

> sudo apt instal openssh-server

and dont forget to star `ssh service`, using this command :

> sudo service ssh start

second, did you can ping the ip of ubuntu using your window?? make sure you connect the `Host OS` (Windows) to client OS (Ubuntu 14.04 on VM).
if you get the reply from ubuntu, mkae sure the `firewall(UFW)` didn't block the ssh service.

third, if all step is ok, try to connect using uty to your ubuntu, if you have get an error please give me the spesific error.
may this help you,